# Why such a bad regeneration of image in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I was working with this image:

[image: http://il9.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/3331691/thumb/1.jpg]

I ran the following code for it in MATLAB:

```
i=imread('1.jpg');
[j p]=deconvblind(i,ones(15,15));
imshow(j);
```

The above code gives me this:

[image: https://ibb.co/dxQauk]

I estimated the PSF of `ones(15,15)` by following the help section of MATLAB. It says:

> "To determine the size of the PSF, examine the blurred image and measure the width of a blur (in pixels) around an obviously sharp object".

So I took the brightest spot there and calculated the distance in pixels between the outer bright edge of spot and the outer edge of blurred or "fading" edge. It was close to 17 pixels. (This is how you do it, right?) I then went on to create a weight array (as demonstrated by help section) with the following code:

```
WEIGHT = edge(i,'sobel',.01);
se = strel('disk',4,0);
WEIGHT = 1-double(imdilate(WEIGHT,se));
[J P] = deconvblind(i,ones(15,15),30,[],WEIGHT);
```

The final output image is:

[image: https://ibb.co/nDmOEk]

Needless to say, it's a bad recreation. What parameters do I need to tweak? Change in PSF or some other change? I tried changing some parameters but couldn't get it any better.

Comment: This is what I got after first three lines of code: https://ibb.co/dxQauk

Comment: Look at your image: the size of the halos around your objects changes from object to object. This is not caused by a convolution. If it were, all halos would be the same size. Therefore, you cannot use deconvolution to restore your image. What do you know about the acquisition system? How are these halos produced?